# How to use Vector and Comparable Interface

Tags: java

I did

```
public class Employee implements Comparable <Object> {
    public int compareTo (Object other ){
```

i did the implementation well (it works fine) and calles it from other class:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Firm {

    private Vector <Employee> employees = new Vector<Employee>();
```

and using in the same class (Firm) Comperator Vector in function :

```
public void SortVector(Vector <Comparable> vector) {
```

and calls it with:

```
SortEmployeesBy(this.employees); ////Error is here
```

and in this line the compiler said:

> The method SortVector(Vector) in the type Firm is not applicable for the arguments (Vector)"

Note: i required to use only vector and need to use SortVector several times so that i need to use the comparator because i have many vector and other classes like Employee, customer, Artist... tha each has own implementation for Comparable

why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: For completeness' sake: Are you aware of [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))?

Comment: i required using only vector, my friend

Comment: By whom? Is this a school assignment? `Vector` shouldn't be used in new code.

Answer (score 2):

Try any one

```
public void SortEmployeesBy(Vector<? extends Comparable<Object>> vector) {..}
public void SortEmployeesBy(Vector<Employee> vector) {...}
```

instead of using

```
public void SortEmployeesBy(Vector<Comparable> vector) {...}
```

---

--EDIT--

You can try with `Firm` class making it parametrized as shown below to **make it more generic**.

```
class Firm<T extends Comparable<Object>> {

    private Vector<T> employees = new Vector<T>();

    public void SortEmployeesBy(Vector<T> vector) {...}
}

Firm<Employee> f = new Firm<Employee>();
```